# What do these two icons mean?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, safety, lead-free, rohs

[image]

Left  one - "no plumbum/lead"

Right one - "triangular invert color no picking by hand"

(found on [BeagleBone Green](https://beagleboard.org/green))

Comment: don't touch with bare hands, sensitive components?

Comment: Knowing nothing about ESD I was wondering "If it contains no lead why am I not allowed to touch it?" :/

Comment: @DarrenNg Well, there's no lead, but nothing says there's no cadmium or mercury or arsenic! (there's almost definitely no cadmium or mercury, there may be some arsenic in the form of gallium arsenide in some optoelectronics though if the board has any. The reason not to touch it, or rather to be careful when touching it, is that it's ESD sensitive.)

Comment: @Hearth So the two warnings are not related at all. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "no Pb" means that only lead-free solder was used. For most of the 20th Century, the most common type of solder was made from lead and tin. Lead may have other uses in electronics, but I can't think of any offhand.  Lead was leaking from landfills containing discarded electronic products. Lead was banned or limited. The device in the photo conforms to the new standards.

The "no hand" symbol tells people to not finger with the board, almost certainly due to digital chips or especially sensitive transistors such as MOSFETS. A little static electricity could damage those components. A lot of static electricity - well, that's just plain bad sensitive components or not.

Answer (score 14):

1. The device contains no lead
2. The device is susceptible to ESD so it should be handled accordingly.

Comment: (2) [Exactly the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic-sensitive_device)